# Does pointing a gun at someone constitute attempted murder?

Tags: criminal-law, murder, weapons, kenya

Is pointing a gun at someone tantamount to attempted murder in Kenya? If not, what would it most likely be?

Comment: Country in question & Jurisdiction?

Comment: Kenya law , but would also like to hear from other jurisdictions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming these are common law crimes (Kenya is a common law country - sort of) or statutory crimes that have codified common law crimes without substantially changing them.

It is not attempted murder - this requires an intent to kill. Pulling the trigger would have that intent, pointing it doesn't.

It is [assault](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assault) if it puts the victim in fear of immediate harm (pretty sure it would).

There are probably some statutory firearms offences too.

Answer (score 3):

(In the U.S.) This is at least assault with a deadly weapon, which is typically a felony.

However, [the context and manner in which the firearm was brandished can result in other charges, or can be found to be justified](https://law.stackexchange.com/a/11911/10).